# Server-side file access works when running on localhost but not when deployed to remote server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, localhost, filesystems

I have this simple AJAX script that prints the file names in a specified directory, which is working when running on localhost:8000 but doesn't work when deployed to the remote server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pdfFilesDirectory = './uploads/pdf/';
console.log("1");
$.ajax({url: pdfFilesDirectory}).then(function(html) {
    console.log("2");
    var document = $(html);
    console.log("3");
    // find all links ending with .pdf 
    document.find('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
        console.log("4");
        var pdfName = $(this).text();
        var pdfUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(pdfName);
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The folder `uploads/pdfs` contains two trivial PDFs, and when I navigate to `localhost:8000`, it correctly prints out the names of these two files in the console.
But, when I upload it as a static page to codeberg, and navigate to it, at https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/, it doesn't get past the AJAX code (try it and see for yourself). In fact, I have some print statements to show that it doesn't seem to see the directory `uploads/pdf/` or perhaps it doesn't have permissions.

I tried checking the CORS Origin Access Control with:

`curl -H "Origin: my.ip.address.here" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose https://tok1n.codeberg.page/fs_test/uploads/pdf/`

and judging by the output it seems to show that it has access to the folder.

The other thing I thought it might be is a specific URI/URL that needs to be appended to `pdfFilesDirectory` such as `file://` or something like that, but I couldn't find what it might be.

In fact, it doesn't seem to work when the files are in the root directory, which tells me it is some sort of URL/URL problem.

I would be grateful if someone could steer me in the right direction, since I am new to this.

Thanks